# What is to be used Singly linked list or Array in the scoreboard code?

Tags: java, arrays, singly-linked-list

I'm creating a program in java to store top 10 highest scores. So, i'm using Array in it. I have question in my mind whether what is to be used singly linked list or array in the program to avoid complexity of the code and make program more efficient.

```
    private int numEntries = 0;
private GameEntry[] board;
public Scoreboard(int capacity){
    board = new GameEntry[capacity];
}
public void add(GameEntry e){
    int newScore = e.getScore();
    if(numEntries<board.length||newScore>board[numEntries-1].getScore()){
        if(numEntries<board.length){
            numEntries++;
        }
        int j=numEntries-1;
        while(j>0&&board[j-1].getScore()<newScore){
            board[j]=board[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        board[j]=e;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this use case, array vs list is hardly a bottleneck for efficiency. Use whatever is easiest to write/read and is most clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases no need to think too much about performance (unless it is huge numbers), you should write as clear as possible, understandable code. Later you may tune it, but first make sure it logically correct and you really need performance improvement.

Also you don't need to implement sorting, use existing utilities.

I would do it like this:

```java
List<GameEntry> arr = new ArrayList<>();
Comparator<GameEntry> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getScore());

public void add(GameEntry e) {
  arr.add(e);
  Collections.sort(arr, cmp.reversed());
  while(arr.size() > capacity) {
    arr.remove(arr.size()-1);
  }
}
```